# Read memory in C

Tags: c, memory

I work on a microcontroller,
and I want to read the contents of the memory after the execution of a code.
I know the address of the memory to read and the size
I tried this method:

```
    const volatile unsigned char *const mem_start = 0xd0000000;

    #define size ((ptrdiff_t)0x1c000)

    unsigned char buff[size];
    ptrdiff_t j;

    for(j =0 ; j< sizeof(buff) ; j++)
    buff[i]= *(mem_start + j);
```

I am looking for another method to read the memory without copying it in a buffert, in the same memory that I want to read it, risk crushing what I'm looking for. and that the buff may overlap for lack of space

Comment: First of all, for any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. That means you could change `*(mem_start + j)` to `mem_start[j]` without any problems.

Comment: What do you mean “buffert buff will be stored in the same memory”? When `buff` is defined with `unsigned char buff[size];`, the compiler will allocate memory for it, and it will not be the same memory as at `mem_start`. And what do you mean “risk overwrite what I seek in memory”? Modifying `buff` will not modify the memory at `mem_start`.

Comment: Now for your problem of reading the memory, you're already are doing it. That's what happens when you put `*(mem_start + j)` (or `mem_start[j]`) on the right side of the assignment, The byte on that location is read and copied into `buff[i]`.

Comment: Probable typo: `buff[j]`.

Comment: I want to read the RAM memory, and normally when I declare the buff the compiler it will allocate the memory in the memory RAM,
so it can be risky of an overlap

Comment: The phrase "read the RAM memory" needs a context and you need to specify what outcome do you expect of this "read". Are you wanting to print the data at that location to a console so that it is displayed to a person or do you want to write a copy of the data to some kind of storage such as a disk or what? One further question is whether the IDE and toolset you are using have a debugger that allows you to display the data at a particular memory location.

Comment: I want to execute a code on the microcontrolleur, after the execution of this code I want to see what it is written in the memory, because the code I will execute it I consider it like a black box;
I want to copy the data to a CSV file
I work on the Aurix microcontroller on IDE Hightec which is the basis of eclipce

Comment: @Aconcagua You can't use `memcpy()` here since the memory is volatile-qualified.

Answer (score 4):

In the statement

```
...= *(mem_start + j);
```

you *are* reading memory. So what more do you want ?

---

By the way, why didn't you use

```
mem_start[j]; ??
```

Comment: I want to read the RAM memory, and normally when I declare the buff the compiler it will allocate the memory in the memory RAM, so it can be risky of an overlap.

Comment: @Rbn: you keep repeating that you want to "read" and what you show is a copy. So what ? Also, I do think that you have a wrong understanding of memory mapping and variable allocation.

Comment: I am looking for another method to read the memory without copying it in a buffert,

Comment: I want to execute a code on the microcontroller, after the execution of this code I want to see what is written in the memory, because the code I will execute it I consider it as a black box

Comment: @Rbn: see ? On a screen ? On some display ? In a remote debugger ? 

By the way, how would a copy to a buffer help you see ?

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate memory with `malloc()`, or as you have, on the stack.  There is no overlap between the two.  `memmove()` can be used if you do have overlap between source and destination;  otherwise, `memcpy()` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
*(mem_start + j)
```

or the more conventional

```
mem_start[j]
```

*is* a 'read' operation, when it is used, say, on the right-hand side of an assignment, or as a parameter in a function call.

So, instead of your own code line:

```
buff[j] = *(mem_start + j);    // I'm assuming 'buff[i]' was a typo
```

which reads from one memory location into another, you could do something like:

```
printf("%hhx", mem_start[j]);
```

which will read the byte from `mem_start` at offset `j` and output it to `stdout` as a hexadecimal representation of the byte value.  Put that in a loop (like you already have it) and you will effectively read from memory, *without* copying what you are reading into a 2nd buffer.

Based on some of your comments, I'm assuming that having the memory contents displayed on screen will suit your needs.  And based on what you say the memory that you want to display will be, I'm assuming that hexadecimal output is suitable.  But there are other choices, like reading from the source memory buffer into a file, or outputting the raw byte values (instead of a representation of those values), etc.

Note that not every combination of input and output is useful, though.  Outputting raw byte values to the terminal screen is likely to produce less-than-useful results, and depending on what you want to do with the data you read out, a file full of hexadecimal representation of the source bytes might not be useful either.  Pick the output destination and output format to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how I can display raw byte values please

Comment: @Rbn : outputting raw bytes to the screen is rarely a suitable choice, depending on the nature of the source data; as you no doubt know, many bytes are non-printing characters; it's often better to display a text representation of the byte value, such as with `printf("%hhx", byte)`;  but you can use, say, `fputc(byte, stdout)`; 'stdout' is of course a pre-defined `FILE *` that (usually) points to the screen; just be aware that outputting the raw bytes like this will often look like "garbage", and can even affect display settings, since several bytes are control characters